# Font size of subscripts too high in classic thesis template

Tags: classicthesis

The font size of the subscripts is too high in my formulas if I use the classic thesis template. Here an example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
  $H^{v_{2\text{2}}}$
\end{document}
```

The size of the first index "2" should be the same as the size of the second index "2". If I use document class "article" instead, both index are the same and correct.

Comment: The first is in math, the second one is in text and an "oldstyle digit" is typeset, since `classicthesis` uses, by default, the `osf` option to `mathpazo`.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for your answer. Is is possible to change it to "normal" Latex behavior? The first index is way to high, which I think confuses the reader. Is there a better solution than to change all numbers by "\text{number}"?

Comment: I don't think that using oldstyle figures in math is desirable.

Comment: @egreg Could you perhaps make that an answer?

Answer (score 1):

The `classicthesis` package loads

```
\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo}
```

(unless called with the `minionpro` option). Thus the difference: in text mode the digits are “oldstyle”, while in math they are lining.

It is possible to change the setup so that digits are oldstyle also in math mode:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{digits}{OT1}{pplj}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{digits}{bold}{OT1}{pplj}{b}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{0}{\mathalpha}{digits}{`0}
\DeclareMathSymbol{1}{\mathalpha}{digits}{`1}
\DeclareMathSymbol{2}{\mathalpha}{digits}{`2}
\DeclareMathSymbol{3}{\mathalpha}{digits}{`3}
\DeclareMathSymbol{4}{\mathalpha}{digits}{`4}
\DeclareMathSymbol{5}{\mathalpha}{digits}{`5}
\DeclareMathSymbol{6}{\mathalpha}{digits}{`6}
\DeclareMathSymbol{7}{\mathalpha}{digits}{`7}
\DeclareMathSymbol{8}{\mathalpha}{digits}{`8}
\DeclareMathSymbol{9}{\mathalpha}{digits}{`9}


\begin{document}
  $H^{v_{2\text{2}}}$ $H^{v_{8}}$
\end{document}
```

but this using a sledgehammer for solving a non problem: you can see that the same problem with `2` arises with `8`.

[image]